# While adding row dynamically using javascript I am incrementing the index value, but getting error

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var rowCount = 1;
    function addMoreRows() {

        rowCount++;
        alert("Hello "+rowCount);
        var recRow = '<p id="rowCount'+rowCount+'">'
                + '<tr><td><form:input path="dynamicRow['+rowCount+'].id"/></td>'
                + '<td><form:input path="dynamicRow['+rowCount+'].name" /></td>'
                + '<td><form:input path="dynamicRow['+rowCount+'].email" /></td></tr>'
                + ' <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="removeRow('
                + rowCount + ');">Delete</a>' + '</p>';

        $('#addedRows').append(recRow);

        //$(document).trigger("addedNewRow", rowCount);
    }

    function removeRow(removeNum) {
        $('#rowCount' + removeNum).remove();
        rowCount--;
    }
</script>
```

This is the script I am using in my jsp page, but while running its throwing an error

```
Invalid property 'dynamicRow[+rowCount]' of bean class [com.sharique.beans.DynamicRowForm]: Invalid index in property path 'dynamicRow[+rowCount]'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "+rowCount"
```

Previously it was working, but during code clean up, I did some change and after that it started throwing this exception. I don't know what is the mistake here.Please help!!

Comment: You're trying to create invalid HTML, `p` and `a` within [`tbody`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody) are not allowed.

Comment: No, its not like that... If instead of rowCount, if I give hardcoded value like 1, then it is working fine

Comment: As per your suggestion, I removed p and a tag, but it still showing the same error.
And if it is then why the hardcoded value is working fine but not with this rowCount variable.... If I write dynamicRow[1].id instead of dynamicRow['+rowCount+'], then it works fine

Comment: No, that is not a problem...it is just the index for list in my controller.
Anyway I tried putting the value 0 also

Comment: Sir, I understand that, I will manage, but the issue is not that one.. error is in dynamicRow['+rowCount+'] area..not there

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes and '+' inside `dynamicRow['+rowCount+']` and check. 
Make it `dynamicRow[rowCount]`